# Inconsistent performance of GPU subclusters

Tags: gpu, slurm, hpc

I'm running my MATLAB code on [subclusters provided by my school](https://www.rcac.purdue.edu/compute/gilbreth). One subcluster named 'G' uses Nvidia A100 GPU card and has 12 nodes (G[000-011]) and 128 cores/node.

Whenever I run my code on G[005] and G[006], my code finishes running in just 2 hours. However, strangely, when I run it on any other nodes (i.e.G[000-004, 007-011]), the computation becomes extremely slow (> 4 hours). Since all the nodes should be using the same hardware, I have no idea what is causing this difference.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on? Below is my SLURM job submission file.

Note that I already consulted with a support center at my school, but they also have no idea about this problem yet, so I thought I could get some help here...

```bash
#!/bin/sh -l
#SBATCH -A standby
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -G 1
#SBATCH -n 12
#SBATCH -t 4:00:00
#SBATCH --constraint="C|G|I|J"
#SBATCH --output=slurm-%j-%N.out
/usr/bin/sacct -j "$SLURM_JOBID" --batch-script
/usr/bin/sacct -j "$SLURM_JOBID" --format=NodeList,JobID
echo "------------------------"
cd ..
module load matlab/R2022a
matlab -batch "myfuncion(0,0,0)"
```

Comment: There could be many possibilities since little is known about the characteristic of your workload.  If IT support can’t give you useful information, you should start from profiling your application. Understand which part of your code consumes the extra time. Or even better if the profiler can tell you which hardware component is the bottleneck.

Comment: Since you’re using NVIDIA gpus, you also have to option of ssh’ing into the worker nodes and launching `nvidia-smi` to monitor the utilization of the GPU devices.

Comment: @fjs Thank you for your advice. Yes, I will try to profile the execution time at each point of the code when it is running on the node that causes the issue.